# how to implement hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Could someone help me how to resolve this error?
I'm trying to implement hibernate to start studying, but I came across this error

I don't know what happened.

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    String sql = "select verson()";
    String resultado = (String) session.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(resultado);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

### Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Not yet implemented
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Not yet implemented
>       at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.resolveResultMapping(NativeQueryImpl.java:503)
>       at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.resolveSelectQueryPlan(NativeQueryImpl.java:437)
>       at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:409)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:1302)
>       at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractQuery.java:1328)
>       at view.main.main(main.java:16)

hibernate util:

```
package util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {

                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();


                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);


                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

      sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void fecharConexoes() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, it looks like you have incompatible versions; you should be using the latest 5.x "final" version. Also, be aware that Hibernate now recommends using the JPA interfaces instead of `Session`, and almost all applications now use managed Hibernate configurations such as with Spring Boot instead of doing things by hand. I haven't used manual Hibernate configuration in 7 years.

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace. According to hibernate docs, 'NotYetImplementedFor6Exception Thrown from methods added for 6.0 that are not yet implemented.'

Comment: @admlz635 i post full stacktrace

Comment: sorry i forgott

Comment: @chrylis
I tried to create from the interface that I downloaded from eclipse but I couldn't create cfg it didn't work which version would I use? And I couldn't download the jpa jar could you give me the link?

Comment: I agree with @chrylis. Hibernate 6.0 is under development, wich explains the thrown exception. You should use 5.x instead (like https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/). How are you adding hibernate to your project?

Comment: I added the jars and codes I showed in the post
could you pass me the jpa 2.2 link?
I tried to download from the eclipse site without success

Comment: Check https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.4/